# What are alternatives to a Septic System

Tags: united-states, contract-law, licensing

I work at a Scout (BSA) affiliated camp. Lately, we have been having legal issues with our kitchen because it does not have a septic system. In the past we have been using a bladder that has been emptied bi-weekly by a port a potty company. We cannot build a septic system at camp because we are surrounded by water, and we have been told septic systems must be built 100 yards from water. What are some Alternatives to a septic system? What can we do about putting in a septic system?

Comment: I believe this would depend on your state/province and municipal bylaws. If you edit your question and tags to include those you might be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: How is this a contract law issue? It seems more related to health and safety codes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [DIY.SE](http://diy.stackexchange.com/) or [Engineering.SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Since you mention "BSA", I assume you're in the United States.  This sort of thing is typically regulated at both the state and local level, but not at the federal level, so you'll need to specify exactly where you are.

Comment: @Ryan I don't think this question can be answered until you give some citation of the law you're violating. Specifying your state is a good start, but please edit the question with the actual code.